# Negative correlation not significant ? How do i interpret it?

Tags: correlation, spss, p-value

There is negative correlation between two variables that I am studying but spss does not show it as a significant correlation (p values are coming out to be greater than .2). So the question is

- How do i interpret this insignificant correlations?

Comment: Please be more specific with your question.

Answer (score 2):

The fact that the correlation is negative means that higher values of one variable are associated with lower values of the other.

The fact that it is not significant means that, if, in the population from which this sample was randomly drawn, the correlation was 0.0, you would get correlations as far from 0 as the one you got p of the time and that p is higher than some arbitrary value chosen for being a benchmark for significance.

Answer (score 0):

If the hypothesis that the correlation coefficient is different from zero was not rejected by the test, then, either the correlation in the population is zero, or the [power](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Statistical_power) of the test was not large enough to detect a non-zero correlation.

Comment: @NickCox That is exactly what my answer says: either it's zero or power is relatively low but we don't know which of the two is the case.